# Do I need to start with a cube to make a rigged model?

Tags: sculpting

Right now I'm not worried about the rigging so much as I am the way it's being made.

I want to make some kind of nessie thing, but I am worried because I didn't start off with the cube, I started off with the UV sphere, because, it seemed easier to work with.

Anyway, it has all these weird angles on it. And when I render it alone they show up. So I'm wondering if I've made a mistake starting with the sphere, and if I should just give up at this point and use the cube?

I seriously don't know how any of this works.

The reason I started with the sphere is because I usually use the sculpt tool to shape things and I couldn't get that to work on the cube for some reason.

[image: The work in progress]

Comment: Nah you're doing fine, we all had a hard time at the beginning. I'd have several suggestions to get you started. 1) If your just starting with Blender (and your computer fulfills the minimum requirements) use Blender 2.8. This will help you because the UI is better and you don't have to relearn things later on 2) Watch lots of tutorials to learn the basics (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF1qEhBSfq4&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6) 2) Do small projects, don't try to do a whole animated character from start to finish right away. This will only get you frustrated.

Comment: You don't have to start with the default cube. You currently have the following issues: 1) Body parts are separate objects. For animation you'd likely want them to be one mesh 2) Topology, the shape the mesh has isn't suitable for good animation. You'd likely need to watch animation tutorials to understand what I mean. 3) The mesh isn't set to smooth shading which is why you see these hard edges.

Comment: The reason why the sculpting doesn't work well on the cube is because you don't have dynamic topology (DynTopo) activated which would add more vertices in areas that require higher detail. Without it you're simply moving existing vertices around. Since a cube only has eight you can't create much of a different shape (without DynTopo).

Comment: you can separate body parts, right? right now the head and arms are separate. but i thought that you could like..select certain parts of the figure, and then separate them from the existing one? I did something similar once in Blender when I was editing meshes from The Sims, but I can't remember how I did it. What I had planned to do was sculpt it and then separate it. Is that possible? Thanks for the info regardless. I guess my comment on 'I've never used blender' is false. I've never made a FIGURE in blender. I do use it for morph targets/ the sims.

Comment: Yes you can separate objects. What I meant was, when you plan on animating a character (and aim for realism) you usually have body parts that would be connected IRL also connected in the model, because it makes the deformation more life like. For example in a human model arm and torso would be part of one mesh so that the shoulder can deform properly when raising the arm. An action figure model on the other hand could have them separated.

Comment: Oh, I read that totally wrong I'm sorry lol. What I thought about doing was like, idk HOW exactly to do it yet, but making all one mesh once I'm done working on the parts, smoothing it out and if I needed to, separating them into parts but keeping them looking like they're connected? Idk, I don't really have the best plan rn lol. But I guess I don't need to do that then. The reason they're currently separated rn is because I couldn't quite make it work using the grab tool with just one sphere.